# Highlighting a row in repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

I want to highlight the first row in the repeater while the repeater loads on the page and then highlighting a row on mouse click.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Board</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Room")%></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Board")%></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: @geek server side without postback

Comment: Are you doing anything else as a result of the click? If not then it doesn't make sense doing it server side

Comment: Yes, On click I need to show the details of the row in a control on the same page

Comment: can you please help me with the code

Comment: Please Help with JQuery, If it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery :  (you said  , if possible)

```
var _=$("table tr:gt(0)");
  _.first().css('background-color','yellow');
  _.on('click',function (){
                          _.css('background-color','');
                         $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ukoXeNEy/4/edit

But to get it done with your aspnet ID's :

```
var _=$("#<%=rptTest.ClientID %> tr:gt(0)");
      _.first().css('background-color','yellow');
      _.on('click',function (){
                              _.css('background-color','');
                             $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    });
```

Comment: Although this answers the original question, it seems that in addition to changing the row colour, they also want to get details about the row they clicked on from the server side.

Comment: @TwentyGotoTen so he should use this http://jsbin.com/ukoXeNEy/6/edit